# Android SMS Broadcast Receiver not working

Tags: android, sms, android-broadcast

I' m trying to build an app that receives notifications of incoming sms. I need help as incoming SMS's are not detected on any device. I am using the following code that I got from here:

http://karanbalkar.com/2014/09/display-incoming-sms-messages-in-android/

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySMSApp extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)){ 
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null){
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++){
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }
            for (SmsMessage message : messages){

                String strMessageFrom = message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                String strMessageBody = message.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message received from:" +strMessageFrom, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Message content" +strMessageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }    
    } 
}
```

And the manifest reads as follows. I have setup the intent receiver to trigger the class above but it seems not to do so. I'm unable to telnet onto the emulator to spoof an incoming sms and so I'm blind as to what's going on.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Follow Mattia's advice. He is correct. Also, just in case you did, don't use the latest target sdk, use the same api level used in the tutorial you found. Things changed a little bit in Kit-Kat/Lollipop with regards to sms, so you may need to update the code from the tutorial if you want to use the latest api level number. Also, it wouldn't hurt to add this if you put it in production: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" /> (to make your app invisible to tablets with no cell phone capability).

Answer (score 2):

In AndroidManifest.xml you use `SMSBroadcastReceiver`, but your `BroadcastReceiver` class name is `MySMSApp`. Also your `<receiver>` element is inside the `<activity>` element.

Try to use this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".MySMSApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```